# How to add QLPreviewController as Subview in objective C - iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, qlpreviewcontroller

In previous iOS versions I used to add the QLPreviewController as a subview. It is very handy to use my own app headers and navigation bar but in iOS 8 it adds a white space just below the header. It is the space for its own navigator bar.

You can see the attached img: [image: screenshot which shows the white bar]

I use this code:

```
QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewController.dataSource = self;
previewController.delegate = self;
previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0;
previewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.containerView.frame.size.width, self.containerView.frame.size.height);
[self addChildViewController:previewController];
[previewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.containerView addSubview:previewController.view];
```

How can i mantain the iOS7 funcionality? I only want to hide the qlpreviewcontroller navigationbar

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm solving the EXACT same problem. The only solution I found so far is the following:

```
//    qlController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds));//self.view.bounds;
//    qlController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[self addChildViewController:qlController];
[self.view addSubview:qlController.view];

NSDictionary *bindings = @{@"qlPreviewController": qlController.view};
qlController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[qlPreviewController]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[qlPreviewController]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings]];

[qlController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Commented lines are legacy code, that worked perfectly on `iOs7`. The main idea is stop using spring and struts and start using auto layout. Results looks good enough, but still there are some problems with rotations.

Works good:
Iphone 4s/5/6/6+ iOs7 portrait + landscape, iOs8 portrait
IPad all models iOs7,8 portrait + landscape

Works bad:
Iphone 4s/5/6/6+ iOs8 landscape : has some spacing between navBar and content. I think it is problem with Apple's QLPreviewController rather than my code.

Comment: Finally i used as a workaround a UIWebView. I don't like it but it works with all versions. Besides my app can't use autolayout it supports old iPads with iOS 5.1.1